# Is there a way to insert arbitrary RTF in latex2rtf output?

Tags: unicode, cjk, latex2rtf

I want to insert the Han ideograph 命 in my LaTeX PDF and my RTF output. I can't figure an easy way to this. So for the PDF I am going to be inserting a PDF file that includes the 命. For the RTF file I can include this font specification at the top in the font table:

```
\f2\fnil\fcharset128 HiraMinProN-W3;
```

I can then isert the ideograph with this:

```
\f2 \'96\'bd \f0
```

Is there any way to do this with `latex2rtf`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution for this special case is to use UTF8 encoding for the input file and enter the chinese character directly (no need to modify the latex2rtf .cfg files) - the following code produces the desired character also when run through pdfLaTeX, so it needs no workaround as e.g. embedding a pdf graphic:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{CJK}
\newif\iflatextortf
\begin{document}
\iflatextortf
\else
\begin{CJK}[]{UTF8}{gbsn}
\fi
Test for a Chinese symbol inserted 命 before this.
\iflatextortf
\else
\end{CJK}
\fi
\end{document}
```

However this doesn't solve the more general question of inserting arbitrary code in the rtf output. This could be done as follows:
Add the font to the file `fonts.cfg` by adding the line

```
Dummy1,HiraMinProN-W3.
```

Add the following line to `direct.cfg`

```
\myhan,{\f*Dummy1*\u26947**}
```

or the following may work, too:

```
\myhan,{\f*Dummy1*\'96\'bd}
```

As I don't have your font, I successfully tested this with

```
Dummy1,Arial Unicode MS.

\myhan,{\f*Dummy1*\u21629**}
```

Now the `\myhan{}` command should be recognized by latex2rtf and converted into the defined string, but this isn't compatible with LaTeX, so you should use conditional processing

```
\documentclass...
...
\newif\iflatextortf
\begin{document}
...
\iflatextortf
... \myhan{} ...
\else
... <your pdf graphic here> ...
\fi
```